# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 10:0 cannot recognize input near 'partitioned' 'by' '(' in serde properties specification

Tags: hive

```
Create table d_rel_t.Acty_dim_Csv(acty_cde           int,
                                  acty_nm            string,
                                  acty_typ           string,
                                  gdgs_ind           string, 
                                  dly_growth_ind     string,
                                  grc_ind            string, 
                                  acty_txn_lob_cde   string,
                                  txn_prd_seg_cde    string
                                 ) 
Row format delimited  fields terminated by ','  
partitioned by(acty_ctgry_cde string);
```

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 10:0 cannot recognize input near 'partitioned' 'by' '(' in serde properties specification

I am getting this error , Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`partitioned by` goes before `row format` specification.

```
create table d_rel_t.Acty_dim_Csv(acty_cde           int,
                                  acty_nm            string,
                                  acty_typ           string,
                                  gdgs_ind           string, 
                                  dly_growth_ind     string,
                                  grc_ind            string, 
                                  acty_txn_lob_cde   string,
                                  txn_prd_seg_cde    string
                                 ) 
partitioned by(acty_ctgry_cde string)
row format delimited fields terminated by ','  
;
```